# How to prove not an integer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

The question I am trying to figure out is

```
Let n and m be positive integer and let d = gcd(n,m). Define l = nm/d
Let k > d. Prove that at least one of the following statements must be false.
a) nm/k is not an integer
b) n | (nm/k)
c) m | (nm/k)
```

I thought about making k be d + 1, but don't know what to do from there.

Comment: Just assume all 3 statements are true and try to work towards a contradiction that $d = \gcd(n,m)$ or one of your other assumptions.

Comment: Notice that $l=\lcm(n,m)$.

Comment: I can't get anywhere. I said that the gcd(n,m) is k and k | n and k | m. But I get stuck after this.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that (b) and (c) are true

(b) n | nm/k $\Rightarrow$ m/k is an integer say $m_k$ (let [nm/k]/n = $m_k$ = m/k) and immediately you see that  k cannot be irrational.

(c) m | nm/k $\Rightarrow$ n/k is an integer say $n_k$

Now nm/k = k.$n_k m_k$ and if (a) is true then this is not an integer $\Rightarrow$ k is not an integer: let k = p/q where q > 1, and p, q are relatively prime. 
Since k = p/q (with q>1) > d then p > d.

From (b) $m_k$ = m/k = m.q/p and as p, q relatively prime then p must divide m. Similarly from (c) p must divide n. So p > d divides both m and n which contradicts d = gcd(m, n).

So, at least one of (a), (b), (c) must be false.

**It appears though that (a) is redundant and one of (b) or (c) must be false**. The proof is similar. From (b) and (c), $m_k$ = m/k and $n_k$ = n/k. Again, k cannot be irrational so let k = p/q with p, q relatively prime but now allow q $\ge$ 1 so that k could be an integer. Again if k > d then p > d.

$m_k$ = m/k = m.q/p and as p, q relatively prime then p must divide m. Similarly p must divide n. So p > d divides both m and n which contradicts d = gcd(m, n).